# Configuration error with MongoDB laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am planning to use MongoDb along with my Laravel project. I am using the jensseger/mongodb extension for it.
I have configured everything. I am getting an error saying mongodb not configured.
This is how my database.php file looks like:

```
'connections' => [
        # Our primary database connection
        'mongodb' => [
            'driver'    => 'mongodb',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,

        ],
```

Answer (score 4):

Double check your configuration in config/database.php

Also make sure that you fire ***php artisan config:cache*** after doing the changes.

Comment: php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Also in my instance the models included: protected connection = "mongodb"

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have `DB_CONNECTION=mongodb` set in your .env file or just replace `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')` with `'default' => 'mongodb'`. I would go with the former, as it's safer to rely only on the .env, rather than hardcoding your default database connection.

Comment: That is already done.
I tries a lot more things and the connection is now established.
The problem now is that I have a authentication enabled in mongo, but when I am trying to access the db through Laravel it is showing error while passing user name and password but without it, it is able to access the db

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan cache:reset`? The error you are having with the authentication now seems to be a cache issue, otherwise post your mongodb configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
   'mongodb' => [
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'options'  => ['database' => 'Database_Name']
    ],
```

After clear cache "php artisan config:cache"

Answer (score -1):

go to .env
Add these lines:

```
MONGO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=your database name
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=your database username if you have
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=your database password if you have
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.